# Show that $(x^2+y^2)^2-2(3x^2-5y^2)^2=z^2$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $(x^2+y^2)^2-2(3x^2-5y^2)^2=z^2$ has no integer solutions which are not $0,0,0$

So I expanded this to get $$-17x^4+60x^2y^2-49y^4=z^2$$

None of the terms on the left share common factors.

Comment: But it does; $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: I guess non trivial solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first solutions to $a^2-2b^2=z^2$. If $a$ and $b$ are both even, then so is $z$, so dividing all three by $2$ gives a smaller solution. Continuing, we reach a solution where at least one of $a$ or $b$ is odd. If $a$ is even, so is $z$, which implies that $b$ is as well (look modulo 4). Thus $a$ is odd, so that $z$ is odd, and then $a^2\equiv z^2\equiv 1\mod{4}$. Thus $2b^2\equiv 0\mod{4}$, so that $b$ is even. So in any such reduced solution, $a$ is odd and $b$ even, which implies that the original solution must be such that the number of powers of $2$ in $b$ exceeds the number in $a$.

Looking at your problem (with $a=x^2+y^2$, $b=3x^2-5y^2$), if $x^2+y^2$ is odd, the above implies that $3x^2-5y^2$ must be even. But this is impossible. Thus $x$ and $y$ must be both odd or both even.

If $x$ and $y$ are both even, then $x^2+y^2$ and $3x^2-5y^2$ are both divisible by $4$, so that $z^2$ is divisible by 16 and then $z$ is divisible by $4$. Dividing $x$ and $y$ by $2$ and $z$ by $4$ then gives a smaller solution. Continuing this process gives a solution where at least one of $x$ and $y$ is odd; since $x$ and $y$ must have the same parity, they must both be odd.

However, this is impossible: if both $x$ and $y$ are odd, then $x^2+y^2\equiv 3x^2-5y^2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, which contradicts the fact that the number of powers of $2$ in $3x^2-5y^2$ must exceed the number in $x^2+y^2$.

Thus there are no integer solutions.

Comment: +1 Just be careful with the $ \gcd(a,b,z) = 1$ assumption and account for it.

Comment: @CalvinLin Happy to if you would clarify your concern. I realize that I was not terribly clear about the fact that the simpler equation is homogeneous, and $x^2+y^2$ and $3x^2-5y^2$ are as well; is that what you're pointing out?

Comment: Yes, one way of phrasing it is that "In order for there to be solutions, $v_2(x^2 + y^2) < v_2( 3x^2  -5y^2)$, and then reach a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean the equation is homogeneous? And how do you determine $b$ is even? And why cant $a^2\equiv z^2\equiv 3$ mod $4$? instead of $1$?

Comment: Odd squares are always $1\mod{4}$, not $3\mod{4}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, your comment made me realize that I'd left out quite a bit of argument here.